# How to build a native Android executable that uses the Boost C++ library

Tags: boost, makefile, android-ndk

I have a problem building a native library for Android that makes use of the Boost C++ library. The link command generated by the ndk-build specifies the boost libraries *after* stdc++, resulting in a few undefined references to STL elements. I can get rid of the link errors (and generate a working library) by editing the link command and moving the boost libraries so they are specified before stdc++.

How can I cause ndk-build to put the boost libraries before stdc++ in the link command? (Or is there another solution to this?)

For reference, my Android.mk file is pasted below.

Thanks,
Shlomy

=============== Android.mk file =====================

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
DEBUG_SERVER := $(HOME)/upontek_Host_Gen_Dev/Host_Infra/NtrigNetPlatform/DebugServer

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ntrig_generic_api

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-write-strings
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    # x86 causes link error if compiling with -fstack-protector
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fno-stack-protector
else
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK -DBOOST_THREAD_LINUX -DBOOST_HAS_PTHREADS -D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS -fexceptions
endif

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    ./inc \
    ../../Common/inc \
    $(NDK_PATH)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include \
    $(NDK_PATH)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include \
    $(BOOST_DIR)/boost_1_45_0 \
    $(DEBUG_SERVER)/Common/inc \
    $(DEBUG_SERVER)/ClientLib/inc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ../src/GenericApi.c ../src/DebugClient.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
    -L$(BOOST_DIR)/build/lib -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_system-mt \
    -lboost_thread-mt

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Sorry for the mismatch between the subject and description - the same problem exists in both an application and a library.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, issue solved. The solution consists of simply adding libstdc++.a to the end of the boost library list - so the linker command actually contains two specifications of this library. Turns out it's okay to have the same library in two places in the link command.